# List of generic interface with generic interface parameter

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I know similar questions have been asked, but I didn't find any which was similar enough to what I did.

Let's say I have this:

```
public interface IData
{
    string Data { get; set; }
}
public interface IJob<out T> where T: IData
{
    T JobData { get; } // works because no setter

    void Run();
}

public class JobAData : IData
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
}

public class JobA : IJob<JobAData>
{
    public JobAData JobData { get; private set; } // implements IJob's get plus a set

    public JobA(JobAData data)
    {
        JobData = data;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        //can use JobData nicely here
    }
}
```

And, because of the out parameter, this also works:

```
List<IJob<IData>> jobs = new List<IJob<IData>>();
jobs.Add(new JobA(new JobAData()));

//in another class, extremely simplified (actually running with Quartz)
foreach (var job in jobs)
{
    job.Run();
}
```

While this works fine, it feels like a hack since I have to remember that `JobA` needs a setter that is not enforced by the interface.
I originally was using a double `IJob` interface (an `IJob` and an `IJob<T>`) but that meant I had to cast from `IJob<T>` to `IJob` and I didn't like that.
Is there any cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Why do you think it is a hack? The point of interfaces is that you don't care what the implementation is, you just want to deal with that contract. Having a get without a set just enforces a readonly contract which is exactly what you need here, all you care about is calling `Run` so we can forget about everything else.

Comment: " I have to remember that JobA needs a setter" - why is that? What will happen if you forget that setter?

Comment: The IJob interface needs to have its data from somewhere. Without a setter,  I need at least a method that would work as a setter, either from constructor or otherwise. I want to enforce a common way (that's why the interface in the first place) but the out parameter disallows me to do it in the same interface

Comment: if you remove the private setter that will work as readonly property and you can still set JobData in constructor.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary yes, I know that. But still that does not force me a contract, which is basically what I am looking for

Comment: there is not much you can do. did you know properties can be implemented as expressions too? for example you could implement `JobAData` like this `public JobAData JobData => null;` which will always return null. as you can see interface has no control over that. `get` is the only contract you can put and that `getter` can be _used_ in different ways.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Why not have `JobAData.Data` have private setter and set it in the constructor?

Comment: @Nkosi because I need to remember to do it by hand, and nothing will complain if I don't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE

My original suggestion was to create an abstract class that sets the Data in the constructor,

```
public abstract class JobBase<T> : IJob<T> where T : IData {

    public JobBase(T data) {
        JobData = data;
    }

    public T JobData { get; private set; }

    public abstract void Run();
}
```

forcing derived classes to set the `JobData` property.

```
public class JobA : JobBase<JobAData> {
    public JobA(JobAData data) : base(data) { }

    public void Run() {
        //can use JobData nicely here
    }
}
```

ORIGINAL ANSWER

Following the abstract base class idea consider a abstract factory method that would force any derived class to provide data, either in the property itself

```
public abstract class JobBase<T> : IJob<T> where T : IData {
    public T JobData { get { return GetData(); } }

    public abstract void Run();

    public abstract T GetData();
}
```

or having a private setter and setting it one time in the constructor

```
public abstract class JobBase<T> : IJob<T> where T : IData {

    public JobBase() {
        JobData = GetData();
    }

    public T JobData { get; private set; }

    public abstract void Run();

    public abstract T GetData();
}
```

Any derived implementations would be forced to implement the `GetData` method.

Comment: I can't test right now, but using an abstract class, couldn't I make the constructor require T instead of having a GetData method?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I asked you that in the comments and you said `because I need to remember to do it by hand, and nothing will complain if I don't`

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I didn't understand you correctly. That is better than the interface, so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you want to enforce setter definition on inheritance which would have accessibility restriction as well! If you define a setter method, you would still end up making it publicly accessible. And, "double `IJob` interface (an `IJob` and an `IJob<T>`) but that meant I had to cast from `IJob<T>` to `IJob`" doesn't sound good to you.

There are not much solutions to this situation but one work around can be restriction using Abstract Classes. What I am suggesting here is something like this:

```
public interface IData
{
    string Data { get; set; }
}
public interface IJob<out T> where T : IData
{
    T JobData { get; }

    void Run();
}

public class JobAData : IData
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Abs_JobA : IJob<JobAData>
{
    public abstract JobAData JobData { get; protected set; }
    public abstract void Run();
}

public class JobA : Abs_JobA
{
    public override JobAData JobData
    {
        get;
        protected set;
    }

    public JobA(JobAData data)
    {
        this.JobData = data;
    }

    public override void Run()
    {
        //can use JobData nicely here
    }
}
```

So now, you do not implement `IJob` to subsequent classes but, rather you extend `Abs_JobA` abstract class.

Comment: How would the List look like then?

Comment: No change! Just tested. :)

Comment: But this means I need two classes for every implementation (the abstract and the actual implementation), not really cleaner...

Comment: Nope! I just made a dummy explanation. You can still make the abstract class as generic as:     
`public abstract class Abs_JobA<T> : IJob<T> where T : IData
        {
            public abstract T JobData { get; protected set; }
            public abstract void Run();
        }

        public class JobA : Abs_JobA<JobAData>`

Comment: That would hide the Interface, basically duplicating it. Why then not just the abstract class with IData?

Comment: Yup! makes more sense to have only `Abs_JobA` and remove `IJob` (in my solution). But, its your call if you want to have accessibility restricted setters or Interface implementations. Code can always change based on the actual requirement.